# How to know alt + ctrl + del combination is clicked in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

I have a `C# winform .Net 4.0 application` in `Windows 7`. The application hosts `COM control`.
When user unlocks the machine with application open, the `COM control` is not refreshed and that section of form is shown as black. To resolve this issue , I handled system unlock event and did an explicit refresh and the issue is resolved. If user `presses alt + ctrl + del combination` and then press `esc key` , system unlock event is not fired. So the issue happens in this case. I can handle `esc key` in the application. But how will find out whether `alt + ctrl + del combination` is pressed before `esc key`?

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292165/how-to-trap-the-keyboard-strokes-on-a-c-sharp-win-forms-application-ctrl-alt

Comment: By "pushes the Esc key" do you mean that the user presses Esc to cancel the unlock sequence, i.e. does not enter a password but just puts the machine back to the screen saver instead of unlocking? I doubt that's possible to catch at all.

Comment: In my machine , if i press alt + ctrl + del combination from desktop , i get screen with options like 'LOCK COMPUTER' , Switch User,Log Off etc. If I press esc key , it goes back to desktop screen .