# How To Hook CTRL+ALT+DEL

Tags: c#

Need To Know if I can Hook CTRL + ALT + DEL Key Combination. for example I have a windows form and I want to limit the user to Open the Task Manager and kill the active processes!

Comment: You can't.  That's sort of the whole point of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trap the keyboard strokes on a c# win forms application (CTRl + alt +Del)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292165/how-to-trap-the-keyboard-strokes-on-a-c-sharp-win-forms-application-ctrl-alt)

Comment: Keeping a user for opening Task Manager should be done via login permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a special keystroke that is impossible to hook into for security purposes.

Comment: You can hook the combination of keys. Just store keydown or key up until you get control+alt+del

Comment: Try it. You can't stop the user from bringing up the task manager this way if they want to.

Comment: Yea, I don't know about interacting with the task manager, but you can get your program to be alerted to the fact that the task manager was opened with the key shortcut.

Comment: People who down voted the question were maybe thinking that I was trying to make any kind of virus or something like that. but no, I was just willing to know if these kind of functionalities are possible or not. Thanks for the answer @LouFranco